# Capture graphics from a full screen cmd console?

Tags: windows, command-line, screen-capture

How do you capture graphics from a program running in a full-screen cmd console?

The Print Screen button does't work, nor does Alt-Print Screen.

I have tried to set the display options on the window to not run full-screen, but it seems to have no effect. the cmd window size remains full screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found this:

> Note: It is **not possible to capture
>   graphics** from full DOS screens under
>   Windows XP. Since this is a limitation
>   of the operating system itself, no
>   screen capture software can get around
>   it. However Microsoft is offering a
>   solution with their product "Virtual
>   PC 2004" for free. Click here for
>   details.

Therefore the easiest solution is like Matt suggests: use a Virtual Machine and take a screenshot of that from your normal OS.

Comment: Didn't work. The program bombs running in a Windows Vista Virtual Machine.
Great idea though. If I don;'t get a solution that works, I'll choose this as the best answer.

Comment: You should then try a Windows XP Virtual Machine, if you're lucky use XP Mode under Windows 7!

Answer (score 1):

Can you run it in a virtual machine than do the capture from the Host computer? If that doesn't work there are a few TSR programs still floating around that will run in the background of Dos and do the capture when a hot key is pressed. The problem with these programs is that alot of times in Dos things get funny when applications are in full screen/ real mode.

If that doesn't work you can google it, seems to be a few programs/hints on how to do it.
[Google Search](http://www.google.com/search?q=dos+screen+capture)

Comment: Usually it's a good idea to post the URLs from the search that are relevant instead of the search results themselves. Google searches will change over time and the top few results may not be relevant anymore if this question is looked at a few years down the road.

Comment: I've searched for some but either couldn't get them to work or I didn't do it right. I tend to believe the guy who posted that it is impossible to capture full screen DOS graphics except running in a Virtual Machine, which I think is a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Alt+Enter key combination to toggle the running Command window between fullscreen and windowed?  That would enable you to use Alt+PrtScrn.

Comment: I tried. It didn't work

Comment: The program starts off in windowed mode but switches to full screen mode when it draws a graph. It is the graph whose image I need to copy.